# playback of array of base64 audio data

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I am using javascript to parse an SWF file and displaying the contents in an HTML5 canvas.

I am having an issue with playing back the audio data from the audiostream swf tags. The audio is split up per frame and I am able to get the audio data into an array of base64 data, in the same order as the frames. Creating/destorying audio elemnts on each frame does not seem like the best way to go about it, but it is the only way I can think of. Is there a better way to go about this?

Note: There are  rewind/fastforward/pause buttons in the swf file as well, so the audio will need to align with the frames when they are sent back, so I don't believe I can just create one long audio file from the smaller bits of data.

Comment: You mean you can pass these base64 strings as the `src` of an HTMLAudioElement and it will be readable?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, if I add one of them as the src of the HTMLAudioElement, about 0.5 seconds worth of audio data will be readable. There is an array of about 2000 of them for one particular file I am working with.

Comment: `.swf` is Shockwave Flash. It won't play on HTML.

Comment: @StackSlave I am well aware of that. I am parsing the tags and manually rebuilding it within the canvas myself.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a convertor to convert the files, then save them the correct way on your Server?

Comment: @StackSlave Do you have a suggestion for a converter that will convert them cleanly? I would very much prefer to do that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making an array in javascript of the index of the sound id, which corresponds with the frame id, and inside of the object it contains an audio element create as I parse the tags. The elements are not added into the DOM, and they are created up front, so they persist for the life of the frame-handler (as they are stored in a sounds array inside of the object), so there is no create/destory cost.

This way, when I play the frames (the visuals) I can call play on the audio element corresponding to the active frame. As the frames control which audio is played, the rewind/fastforward functionality is retained.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to load these audio files as [AudioBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) and play them through the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

What you currently have are data-URLs, that do represent full audio file (with metadata).
Loading all of these in Audio elements may indeed not be a good idea, for a start [because some browsers may not let you do so](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162627#c1), and then because HTMLMediaElement are not meant for perfect timing.

So you will need to first fetch all these data-URLs to get back their actual binary content in ArrayBuffers, then you'll be able to extract the raw PCM audio data from these audio files.

```js
// would be the same with data-URLs
const urls = [
  "kbgd2jm7ezk3u3x/hihat.mp3",
  "h2j6vm17r07jf03/snare.mp3",
  "1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3",
  "h8pvqqol3ovyle8/tom.mp3"
].map( (path) => 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/' + path );
const audio_ctx = new AudioContext();

Promise.all( urls.map( toAudioBuffer ) )
  .then( activateBtn )
  .catch( console.error );

async function toAudioBuffer( url ) {
  const resp = await fetch( url );
  const arr_buffer = await resp.arrayBuffer();
  return audio_ctx.decodeAudioData( arr_buffer );
}

function activateBtn( audio_buffers ) {
  const btn = document.getElementById( 'btn' );
  btn.onclick = playInSequence;
  btn.disabled = false;
  // simply play one after the other
  // you could add your own logic of course
  async function playInSequence() {
    await audio_ctx.resume(); // to make noise we need to be allowed by a user gesture

    let current = 0;
    while( current < audio_buffers.length ) {
      // create a bufferSourceNode, no worry, it weights nothing
      const source = audio_ctx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audio_buffers[ current ];
      // so it makes noise
      source.connect( audio_ctx.destination );

      // [optional] promisify
      const will_stop = new Promise( (res) => source.onended = res );

      source.start(0); // start playing now

      await will_stop;
      current ++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>play all in sequence</button>
```